# Return samples of phrases containing hit on keywords in fulltext search mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

If you have records of documents in mysql, and you do a full text search for keywords in your documents, how do you return not just the id of the record, but also a sample phrase from each document that contain the keywords?

eg searching for "superman"

might return two records...

"when can I pick up my suit?" **Superman** asked the drycleaner

"and as far as he's concerned, **Superman** has no chance"

Comment: Why not just select the document in the select portion when you do the full text search? That would return the document portion along with the id

Comment: Thanks John. Wouldn't that return the whole document, rather than just a few words around the found keyword? Or is that the idea, and you then use php to extract a sentence containing the keyword from the doc?

Comment: well I don't know. it depends on what you are storing in that column.. if its a whole document then you may want to use a string method to find a few words.. or you can do it on the server side in php. if you would like to clarify in more detail then I could probably write an answer for you ;)

Comment: if you want to do this in php see this post. it does what you want.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684754/grab-x-number-of-words-before-and-after-a-given-keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a mysql solution to your problem

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS(' ',
            TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 SUBSTRING(bigstr, 1, INSTR(bigstr, 'Superman') - 1 ),
                 ' ',
                 -8)
            ),
            TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 SUBSTRING(bigstr, INSTR(bigstr, 'Superman')),
                 ' ',
                 5)
            )
  )
FROM longstring
```

i just made a sample table. so for your case change any instance of bigstr to the column that has the data (aka your document). and then the strings that contain 'Superman' is the keyword. so change that to whatever you want to be the word you are searching for and it'll return a few words before and after.. I just did -8 which will return 7 words before the keyword and 5 to return 4 after.. because thats how your example looked.. but if you change the -8 and 5 to any number it'll be the number of words before and after

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5a778/2)

Comment: Wow - thank you John. I will opt for the mysql solution over the php one. I have to work today, so this is just going to sit here teasing me all day until I can get home to implement it. I'm happy to Paypal you something for this full solution, as it has saved me time trying out yet another third party site search solution, when this will do nicely for the small amount of documents I need to index.

Comment: @Shaun no need to paypal me.. this is not something that takes days of work.. :) if you need any more help on it just give me a buzz and I can try and help! this was a good challenge for me as i've never done that before so i learned a new thing or two on the way.. thats why i'm on here to learn new things and get better at what I do.. and answering questions helps a LOT with that!

Comment: I've got the code in and it's working beautifully John. One thing to make it perfect - I was wondering how to maintain the case of the bigstr? eg currently if the bigstr is "Holy cow, what a grand day", and the search term  is COW (all upper case), how do you get it to return "Holy cow, what a grand day" as opposed to "Holy COW, what a grand day"? Or is that beyond what mysql can do? Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: @Shaun two things... is COW in the string itself? or just the search term? I also edited my answer. if you want to try that :)

Comment: I'll try that edit. COW would just be the search string, and the text being searched might have Cow, cow, COW etc. Currently, when the CONCAT_WS phrase is returned, the search string is replacing the hit within the searched text. So if the text is "Cow one - turn to the left please", and someone searches for "cow", the phrase returned is "cow one - turn to the left please" rather than "Cow one - turn to the left please". If the case in the text being searched would remain unchanged, this would be a perfect query for site searches. Thanks John

Comment: @Shaun you can remove the middle part completely to solve that issue you just have to not remove the "superman" from the second trim... see my edit

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I can't believe all that functionality was able to be done in mysql instead of php. Thank you John.

Comment: @Shaun its quite amazing what you can do in MySQL :)... if you want to 'pay' me you can do this.. every day for a few days if you want you can throw an upvote on my answers :) if you do more than 3 they will be flagged as chronic upvoting.. so if you want to throw a few my way for a few days it would be really appreciated. but yea theres no need to pay me with money lol its a nice gesture though!

Comment: Perfect, thank you. To those who wonder: add "WHERE bigstr LIKE '%Superman%'" to filter the results.

Comment: @Konservin also look at the edit history ... that probably filtered it as well :)

Comment: @Konservin yea I had it so it included the word in the search but the OP wanted it removed :) but yea that is another good way to do it too! thanks for your kind comments and the +1 i'll reciprocate a few :)

Comment: I think there is a minor problem. Imagine searching for 'super'. Result will be "..concerned, Super man has..", with a space. This goes beyond what OP asked, but how would you go about that?

Comment: @Konservin not sure if i'm following... are you looking for a space before the few words? a space like at the beginning of the string? or at the end?

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear, and the example was wrong, too. Seaarching for 'Super' is no problem, but searching for 'man' is, because this query puts a space before the search string. This: 
`SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(bigstr, 1, INSTR(bigstr, 'man') - 1 ), ' ', -8)), TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(bigstr, INSTR(bigstr, 'man')), ' ', 5))) FROM longstring`

results in "Kent, whose alter ego is known as Super man, is a ..."

Not really a problem though

Comment: @Konservin yea this is meant for a full word search not a search within a word